# Extract URL using xpath

Tags: html, xpath, web-scraping

What xpath should i use to extract the "URL" and title="TEXT" from this html code:

```
<div class="VersionAnglaise"> <a href="URL" title="Version Anglaise"
 class="LienVersionAnglaise"><strong>Version anglaise</strong></a> </div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

To get title attribute :

```
//div[@class='VersionAnglaise']/a/@title
```

To get href attribute :

```
//div[@class='VersionAnglaise']/a/@href
```

You can combine both using XPath union (`|`) :

```
//div[@class='VersionAnglaise']/a/@title | //div[@class='VersionAnglaise']/a/@href
```